# DVB-C Card on a server

Tags: networking, server, mediaserver, dvb

I'm setting up a Ubuntu "server" (old PC, Athlon X2) for the entire house. Mainly it's supposed to be a File- and Media-Server which can be done without a GUI.

There's a connection for cable TV in the "server room". I wondered if it is possible to equip the server with a DVB-C card and use it to record TV and radio broadcasting. Or even better, to distribute the recordings over ethernet to other PCs (all different systems, mainly Windows 7 and Mac OS).

If such a distribution were possible would it result in a decreasing audio and video quality?

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Comment: Well, several solutions to that exist. Have a look at https://tvheadend.org/ (for example) and make sure you buy the right things for your setup: software, country, service provider, etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? if yes could you please answer your own question to explain what you did.